# How to download attachment in Flutter using enough_mail

Tags: flutter, dart, smtp, imap

I need to download the attachment from the mime message object. Bellow, I have added my class file. Which came with the mime message. Need help to extract the attachments and download them.

```
class EmailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  EmailScreen({
    Key key,
    this.mimeMessage,
    this.userInfo
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MimeMessage mimeMessage;
  final UserInfo userInfo;

  @override
  EmailScreenState createState() => EmailScreenState(
      mimeMessage: mimeMessage,
      userInfo: userInfo
  );

}

class EmailScreenState extends State<EmailScreen> {

  MimeMessage mimeMessage;
  UserInfo userInfo;
  EmailScreenState({Key key,this.mimeMessage,this.userInfo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the below code that I have used to download attachments using [enough_mail 1.3.6](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_mail).

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: mimeMessage.findContentInfo().length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    ContentInfo contentInfo = mimeMessage
        .findContentInfo()[index];
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: Text(
              contentInfo.fileName,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            )
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                MimePart mimePart = mimeMessage.getPart(contentInfo.fetchId);
                Uint8List uint8List = mimePart.decodeContentBinary();
  
                MySnackBar.show(
                  context,
                  MySnackBar.loadingIcon,
                  "Downloading....!"
                );
  
                saveFile(context,uint8List,contentInfo.fileName).then((value){
                  MySnackBar.hide(context);
                  if(value){
                    MySnackBar.show(
                      context,
                      MySnackBar.successIcon,
                      "Completed!"
                    );
                  }else{
                    MySnackBar.show(
                      context,
                      MySnackBar.errorIcon,
                      "Something went wrong!"
                    );
                  }
                }).catchError((err){
                  MySnackBar.hide(context);
                  MySnackBar.show(
                    context,
                    MySnackBar.errorIcon,
                    "Something went wrong!"
                  );
                });
  
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.download,
              color: Colors.grey,
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
)



Future<bool> saveFile(BuildContext context,Uint8List uint8List, String fileName) async {

    Directory directory;

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {

          directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
          String newPath = "";
          print(directory);
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");

          for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
            String folder = paths[x];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/" + folder;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }

          newPath = newPath + "/NetxMail";
          directory = Directory(newPath);

        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (await requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
          directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        await directory.create(recursive: true);
      }

      if (await directory.exists()) {
        File file = new File('${directory.path}/$fileName');
        print("file path = ${file.path}");
        await file.writeAsBytes(uint8List);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var result = await permission.request();
      if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```